# Is this how to structure classes for DDD?

Tags: domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

Assume I have the relationship where every customer has an address (which in this case, is an entity), like below:

Customer{  Id, Name, MyAddress (instance of Address)  }

Should I be allowing a structure that exposes the following option:

```
MyCustomer.MyAddress.Street = "Pine Street";
CustomerRepository.Save(MyCustomer);
```

Should this cascade a save, both for the Customer class and for the Address class? Or, is it better to perform the following:

```
MyCustomer.MyAddress.Street = "Pine Street";
AddressRepository.Save(MyCustomer.MyAddress);
```

Unfortunately, Address really is a value object, but I cannot make it interchangable like DDD requires as the Id tag is present; for example, if I did the following:

```
Customer1.setAddress(Customer2.getAddress());
```

Both Customer1 and Customer2 now have the same binding to the *same* record, which is dangerous.

Comment: Why is address an entity?

Comment: When you're modelling the domain, the database _doesn't exist_. Also you're modelling domain concepts not structures. It's debatable if Address is part of Customer or it's associated with it. Customer1 and Customer2 don't have a binding to the same record, because that's database language which is evil in DDD, at most they _refer_ to (or they share) the same Address with all the implications. DDD is simple IF you're modelling the domain as it is and you forget about OOP, classes, entities, value objects, ORM, tables, one-to-many etc. All these are technical details, they're less important

Comment: @JefClaes purely for point of example in this case.

Comment: @MikeSW, that makes complete sense, but my question is more how to make this DDD a reality. I cannot, realistically, ignore ORM, tables etc. when it comes to actually programming it.

Comment: At this point you're doing design so you care only about the Domain. When you're working with persistence (this should be the last step in the app) you deal with how to map the domain objects but ONLY after you know what the domain (and the rest of the app) expects from persistence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of your samples is DDD. Each one is simple CRUD.

1. Don't "set fields". Do meaningful operations.

```cs
customer.MoveTo(new Address(...))
customer.FixAddressTypo(new Address(...))
```

1. Repositories are for aggregates, not any entities. Identify your aggregates. http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/
2. Why not map the Addres value Object as a bunch of fields in the Cutomers table? You don't need separate table just because you have a separate class.
3. Value objects should be immutable.

Comment: Actually those behaviours don't belong to customer, they are _use cases_ of customer. 1. In the Domain layer, Repositories are for aggregate roots but outside the domain they can be for entities or view models etc. It's important to specify this distinction, the repository pattern isn't used only with DDD. 2.  When talking about domain modelling, we don't care about db, so we don't care about how a value object is mapped.

Comment: "Don't "set fields". Do meaningful operations." Brilliant, that clears up a lot for me. I was indeed not making the transition from CRUD to DDD. Regarding point 2, let's say address was optional? Or specific fields inside the address were optional. Now I would have nulls in the table, or at the very least have to denormalize it? @Mike that's a point I believe I was making re persistence; repositories are a design pattern that can be used in _multiple_ places.

Comment: @MikeSW, what's an example then that is not a use case? What's the distinction?

Comment: @AdrianGW I've [blogged about it here](http://www.sapiensworks.com/blog/post/2013/11/08/Domain-Modelling-Object-Behaviour-and-Use-Cases.aspx)